# Create object using of vs new

Tags: java, lombok

During implementing my task, I saw other developers, they create a class using `@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)` which made the class constructor private. Then, they create an object using `of` instead.

What is the difference between create using `new` and `of`?

```
A a = new A();
A a =  A.of();
```

```
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class A
{
    @NonNull
    String data;

    public static A of() 
    {
        return new A();
    }

 }
```

Comment: I believe `of()` is a method they have implemented? We would not be able to tell you the difference unless you provided code for that method.

Comment: @Dylan yeah it's a static factory method.. like in the `List` class you have `static <E> List<E> of(E e1)`

Comment: @Dylan, I've already edited it. Thank you!

Comment: @Kartik My bad, so it supports initiating the List with items passed to of()?

Comment: From the code @BunthaiDeng provided I see no difference

Comment: I think it's a design pattern going on these days to make the code more functional and readable.

Comment: @Dylan, this is the reason I am wondering too,

Comment: @BunthaiDeng Read the answer below I think it explains pretty well. I learnt something!

Comment: I would shoot whoever wrote that abomination...

Comment: @paulsm4, What is wrong? It's just an example.

Comment: `of` is most likely a static constructor that does the `new` for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over time, it has become clear that, since you don't name parameters on the call, it is difficult to create objects using various methods, if the optional values are of the same type.

One (fairly dumb) example would be a `Person` class, which might allow specifying just the first name or the last name. In that case, the following constructors wouldn't work:

```
Person(String firstName, String lastName)

Person(String firstName)

Person(String lastName)
```

The first one is fine, but the other two are in conflict, and it cannot be resolved, because you cannot name the constructor or the parameter.

Using static factory methods allows naming the methods where necessary:

```
Person of(String firstName, String lastName)

Person ofFirstName(String firstName)

Person ofLastName(String lastName)
```

The general `of` is used when you don't need to name it. It can still be overloaded in the same manner constructors could be overloaded, e.g. you might also have:

```
Person of(String firstName, String lastName, int age)
```

---

Although not used as often for classes, a factory method might also return a subclass, if deemed necessary.

For interfaces, a factory method like that is a nice convenience for instantiating an object implementing the interface, instead of having the factory method in a different class.

Prior to interface static method, the JDK implemented `Arrays.asList(...)` for creating a list of explicitly given objects. With the introduction of interface static methods to the language, that method is now (also) implemented on the `List` interface itself as `List.of(...)`.

In addition, they also added convenience methods for `Set.of(...)` and `Map.of(...)`.

Comment: Eg. For List.of(...) you'll get an immutable object, so you can just read it and cannot alter. Not sure if is the same when you try with your own class (Person.of)

Comment: @TraianGEICU It's entirely up to you, whether the object is mutable or not. Using `of()` has nothing to do with that.

Comment: List<String> li = List.of("a","b");
List<String> lm = new ArrayList(List.of("a","b"));
both return a list 
li.remove(0) get exception due to immutable result of List.of,
so if need mutable then should have a constructor that accept ouptut of List.of
But as I seen of() is generating always immutable realted to java implementation 
and not writting some custom class with custom implementation for of().Eq:
 static <E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2) {
        return new ImmutableCollections.List12<>(e1, e2);

Comment: if i made my custom class and implement of() them i could get what ever object type (mutable or not). Partially agree that I could have what kind of object I want from of(), but just if made my own implementation.

Comment: @TraianGEICU My previous comment was a response to your *"Not sure if is the same when you try with your own class (Person.of)"*, where you are in total control of whether that return a mutable or immutable `Person` object. I was in no way trying to say that you could make `List.of()` return a mutable list, since the **documentation** of the [`of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)) method specifically states: *"Returns an **unmodifiable** list"*

Comment: Thx. for clarification. It's fine now your initial response  concerning custom class (Person).

Answer (score 0):

I think they want the chain to look better in some sense. I can't think of any other explanation why you would want to couple your classes to another constructor method.

So instead of,

```
someChain.thenApply(i -> new A().setVar1(var1).setVar2(var2).someMethod());
```

you can do,

```
someChain.thenApply(i -> A.of().setVar1(var1).setVar2(var2).someMethod());
```

they maybe thinking the second one looks better.